# SQL Server IN query odd behaviour

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm getting some really odd results in a database that I've inherited.

```
select [property].entity_id
from [property]
where [property].entity_id in (select [bankdata].entity_id from [bankdata])
```

and

```
select [property].entity_id
from [property]
where [property].entity_id NOT in (select [bankdata].entity_id from [bankdata])
```

Are bringing back some of the same values?

I'm trying to find property.entities that have no parent value (orphans).

For a bit of background:

[`BankData`] is a look up table containing Entity IDs and Parent IDs (Parent IDs are used later down the line).
[`Property`] is a table containing all kinds of additional details.
[`Entity_Id`] is the primary key for both.

I know the table names aren't great, but as I say I've inherited the DB.

Only thing I can think of is data corruption of some kind?

There are also 139912 rows returned in query:

```
select [bankdata].entity_id from [bankdata]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Must be some kind of data corruption or MSSQL 2005 specific issue. I would extract-transform-load the db to MySQL and see if I get the same issue

Comment: It should not be possible to get overlapping results from those queries. Can you give an example of rows that are identical and are returned from both queries?

Comment: @jpw The Id 583 comes back in both queries.

Comment: @neelsg I think you're probably right.  Tempted to create a new DB and copy over the data to check.

Comment: If I explicitly put in 583 to the query (select [bankdata].entity_id from [bankdata] where entity_id=583) then nothing comes back (as expected!)

Comment: is `entity_id` nullable?

Comment: Can you post your exact table structures and few rows of data? ID 583 is not much of an info to start with.

Comment: @Jodrell the values are not nullable

Comment: @NenadZivkovic 
[BankData] has
Entity_Id (PK, int, not null)
Bank_Id (FK, int, not null)

[Property] has Entity_id (PK, int, not null) and lots (hundreds!) of extra fields, however for the queries above I only care about the entity_id field

Comment: Are you absolutely sure above queries are **exactly** the ones you are running? You are using `(select [bankdata].entity_id from [bankdata])` and not something like `(select entity_id from [bankdata])`? Are you absolutely sure column name is `entity_id` and not `EntityID` or something similar?

Comment: @NenadZivkovic yep, that's a copy and paste job.  I was using entity_id initially, but added [bankdata]. to be 100% certain it wasn't using the wrong table.

Comment: Also, if I add " and entity_id = 583" at the very end, nothing is returned.  MUST be corruption somewhere.  I'll try @neelsg suggestion and move the data out somewhere else.

Comment: I ran an import/export task to copy the tables.
Re-ran the query against the new tables:

    select [NEWProperty].entity_id from [NEWproperty] where [NEWproperty].entity_id in (select [NEWbankdata].entity_id from [NEWbankdata]) order by entity_id 

Results against these tables are as expected.

Must be some corruption / caching issue.

At least I now know I've not gone crazy!

Comment: There is no such thing as "corruption/cashing issue". You must be missing something. Double check if there are any difference between old and new tables like different datatypes, collations, lengths,  identity on/off, null/not null... Check if sub-query results from both tables are the same? Try newProperty with old BankData and vice-versa..

Comment: @NenadZivkovic I've seen a few issues with SQL server over the years...  However, I used SSIS to export the data back into the same data base (different target table names), all datatypes etc are identical.  Using [NewProperty] with [BankData] gives the correct (expected) result.  Using [Property] with [NewBankData] also gives the expected result.  [NewProperty] with [NewBankData] gives the expected result.  [Property] with [BankData] gives wrong (original) result.